# Show labels in X axis in R

Tags: r, time, time-series, label, boxplot

I am plotting a boxplot of streamflow data, but it is not showing at the x-axis the names of all stations. The boxplot keeps an empty name between two stations names as shown in the figure. How is possible to show the names of all stations?

This is my code

```
boxplot(mean~station,DSF_moments, col="cyan", ylab ="mean flow [m3/s]", main="Boxplot of mean annual flow for stations at Salt and Verde Rivers", cex=0.5)
```

and this is an image[image]

Comment: This happens automatically so that the labels do not overlap. You may want to build a customized x axis manually; try `boxplot(..., axes=FALSE); axis(1, cex.axis=0.5); axis(2, cex.axis=1);box()`

Comment: To add to jay.sf you can easily confirm this is true by reducing the font-size to something very small or flipping the coordinates (```+coord_flip()``` to see them showing up then.

Comment: @Fnguyen OP isn't talking about `ggplot2` though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here an example how to customize axes with `boxplot`.

```
op <- par(mfrow=c(1, 2))  ## set par

## left panel
boxplot(v ~ g, dat, cex=0.5)

## right panel
boxplot(v ~ g, dat, cex=0.5, axes=F)
labs <- unique(dat$g)
axis(1, seq(labs), labels=FALSE)
axis(2, cex.axis=1)
mtext(labs, 1, 1, at=seq(labs), las=2, cex=.8)
box()

par(op) ## reset par
```

[image]

---

*Data:*

```
dat <- data.frame(v=rnorm(1200), g=month.name)
```